# Caching image requests through PHP - If-Modified-Since not being sent

Tags: php, apache, caching, header

I am serving images through php and having some problems setting it up to respond with 304 headers to save on load time.

Most of the code below I found on php.net. It works, however ALWAYS responds with 200. **For some reason the If-Modified-Since header is not being received on any requests even though I am sending the Last-Modified header initially.** This is being done on an apache server. Any idea what might be wrong?

[Example here.](http://louiswalch.com/beta/304_test/)

This page will load the image from disk and display it to browser, along with sending a Last-Modified header. If you refresh the page, the browser doesn't send a If-Modified-Since header like it should.

```
define('SITEPATH', (dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == '/') ? '/' : dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']).'/');

$load_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . SITEPATH . 'fpo_image.jpg';

// Get headers sent by the client.
$headers    = apache_request_headers(); 
$file_time  = filemtime($load_path);

header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $file_time).' GMT');

if (isset($headers['If-Modified-Since']) && (strtotime($headers['If-Modified-Since']) == $file_time)) {

    header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
    header('Connection: close');

} else {

    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
    header('Content-Length: '. filesize($load_path));
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');                         

    readfile($load_path);

}
```

Comment: +1 for question! A very similar problem with If-Modified Since header returning the full content instead of 304: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810806/cached-php-generated-thumbnails-load-slow-how-to-find-problem-solution-from-wat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it should be

```
if (isset($headers['If-Modified-Since']) && (strtotime($headers['If-Modified-Since']) >= $file_time)) {
```

Checking if the modified time is greater than or equal rather than just equal. Although I do understand the two values *should* be the same.

Comment: Any idea why the 'If-Modified-Since' is not being received by php for subsequent requests? I am debugging the $headers value and it never shows up in there. Supposedly all you have to do is set a 'Last-Modified' and it should show up.

Comment: Are you sure your browser is sending it? Use a plugin like LiveHTTPHeaders to verify that. Also when I do it I use $_SERVER[] rather than apache_request_headers()

Comment: Yea, I checked both _SERVER and apache_request_headers() very strange. Maybe I should put up an example to show.

Answer (score 5):

**mandor at mandor dot net** [posted a solution](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#61903) at the PHP.net documentation for the header function which worked for me:

```
<?php

        // Test image.
        $fn = '/test/foo.png';

        // Getting headers sent by the client.
        $headers = apache_request_headers();

        // Checking if the client is validating his cache and if it is current.
        if (isset($headers['If-Modified-Since']) && (strtotime($headers['If-Modified-Since']) == filemtime($fn))) {
            // Client's cache IS current, so we just respond '304 Not Modified'.
            header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($fn)).' GMT', true, 304);
        } else {
            // Image not cached or cache outdated, we respond '200 OK' and output the image.
            header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($fn)).' GMT', true, 200);
            header('Content-Length: '.filesize($fn));
            header('Content-Type: image/png');
            print file_get_contents($fn);
        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

After searching for a while, I've found the answer. The browser didn't cached anything (and didn't send the `If-Modified-Since`) until I sent the following header:

```
Cache-Control: private;
```

After doing this all worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use Keith's solution with combination of azkotoki's and Zsolti's posts above to make everything work as required.

so, final example would be:

```
<?php

    // Test image.
    $fn = '/test/foo.png';

    session_cache_limiter(false);
    header('Cache-Control: private');

    // Getting headers sent by the client.
    $headers = apache_request_headers();

    // Checking if the client is validating his cache and if it is current.
    if (isset($headers['If-Modified-Since']) && (strtotime($headers['If-Modified-Since']) == filemtime($fn))) {
        // Client's cache IS current, so we just respond '304 Not Modified'.
        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($fn)).' GMT', true, 304);
    } else {
        // Image not cached or cache outdated, we respond '200 OK' and output the image.
        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($fn)).' GMT', true, 200);
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($fn));
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        print file_get_contents($fn);
    }

?>
```

Comment: This worked for me, combined with using $_SERVER["HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE"] instead of $headers

Answer (score 0):

Check if sessions are being used on that page, If so, try this:

```
session_cache_limiter(false);
```

If the above worked, here's the explanation:

Php's session mechanism sends some automatic cache-related headers in order to improve the session cookie privacy, avoiding it to be cached by intermediate proxyes:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php

These automatic headers cause the browser not to ever send the If-Modified-Since header, as they instruct it to not to perform any caching at all.